# UIGestureRecognizer doesn't call action until next run loop iteration

Tags: ios, swift, uigesturerecognizer

I'm using a custom subclass of `UIPanGestureRecognizer`, and triggering the target's action by setting `self.state = .began`. However, from what I can tell, the `UIGestureRecognizer` handling of state changes won't actually call the target's action until the next runloop iteration.

This means that by the time my `handlePanGesture()` method is called on the target, the `UITouch` which triggered the gesture may have moved slightly. If the touch is moving quickly, the difference between the touch down location and the `location(in: view)` in `handlePanGesture()` can be tens of pixels or more. Since I'm using the gesture recognizer to track the dragging of views with sizes on the order of tens of pixels, this loss of precision is unacceptable.

To work around this, I have been using the delegate method `gestureRecognizer(gestureRecognizer:shouldReceive:)` to determine the touch down location when it actually occurs. For the most part, this is effective, but it means that the pan gesture recognizer's `translation(in:)` method is returning values that are offset by the same amount that the touch location was before (since it expects to be used in combination with the location returned by `location(in:)` when called from the `handlePanGesture()`, not the earlier location that I am tracking from the delegate method).

Has anyone else experienced this issue or found a workaround? Right now, the only way I can see is to track the movement of the touch between `gestureRecognizer(gestureRecognizer:shouldReceive:)` and the first call to `handlePanGesture` and then save that as a constant adjustment to `translation(in:)`, but I'd like to know if there's a cleaner solution out there...

EDIT:

To reproduce this behavior, use the following view controller and `UIPanGestureRecognizer` subclass:

```
import UIKit

class ImmediatePanGestureRecognizer: UIPanGestureRecognizer {
    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent) {
        super.touchesBegan(touches, with: event)
        self.state = .began
    }
}

class ViewController: UIViewController, UIGestureRecognizerDelegate {
    var originalPoint1: CGPoint?
    var myView1 = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 10, y: 100, width: 20, height: 20))

    var originalPoint2: CGPoint = .zero
    var myView2 = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 10, y: 200, width: 20, height: 20))
    var animator1: UIViewPropertyAnimator?

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        myView1.backgroundColor = .red
        self.view.addSubview(myView1)

        myView2.backgroundColor = .blue
        self.view.addSubview(myView2)

        let gestureRecognizer1 = ImmediatePanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.panGesture1(_:)))
        self.myView1.addGestureRecognizer(gestureRecognizer1)

        let gestureRecognizer2 = ImmediatePanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(self.panGesture2(_:)))
        gestureRecognizer2.delegate = self
        self.myView2.addGestureRecognizer(gestureRecognizer2)
    }

    @objc func panGesture1(_ recognizer: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
        if recognizer.state == .began {
            if myView1.frame.contains(recognizer.location(in: self.view)) {
                originalPoint1 = myView1.center
            }
        } else if recognizer.state == .changed {
            if let originalPoint = self.originalPoint1 {
                let translation = recognizer.translation(in: self.view)
                myView1.center = CGPoint(x: originalPoint.x + translation.x, y: originalPoint.y + translation.y)
            }
        } else {
            originalPoint1 = nil
        }
    }

    @objc func panGesture2(_ recognizer: UIPanGestureRecognizer) {
        if recognizer.state == .began {
        } else if recognizer.state == .changed {
            let translation = recognizer.translation(in: self.view)
            myView2.center = CGPoint(x: originalPoint2.x + translation.x, y: originalPoint2.y + translation.y)
        }
    }

    func gestureRecognizer(_ gestureRecognizer: UIGestureRecognizer, shouldReceive touch: UITouch) -> Bool {
        originalPoint2 = myView2.center
        return true
    }
}
```

When built and run, note that pan gestures which start inside the red square and then quickly move outside will not register in `panGesture1(_:)` as having occurred inside the bounds of the view. The blue square does not have this issue, but instead such pan gestures will result in the blue square trailing the touch by a small amount.

Comment: I don’t get it.  You never create a ImmediatePanGestureRecognizer so what is it for?

Comment: Whoops, that was an oversight. Try the updated code. I've also narrowed down that the issue only seems to occur near the edge of the screen...

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/2887512-preferredscreenedgesdeferringsys  Could be relevant?

Comment: Ooh interesting... very possibly! Will test this and report back

Comment: Unfortunately overriding `preferredScreenEdgesDeferringSystemGestures` and returning `[.left, .right]` did not seem to have any effect.

Comment: Did you try this in a simulator or an actual iphone? If you didn't, can you try this on a actual iphone and report back?